# Slicing a list at integer of when an element is different from the previous

Tags: python, grasshopper

I need to be able to slice a list of points into multiple sublists, to act as a guide for slicing another list.

```
a = 1 # just an example
b = 2 # just an example
c = 3 # just an example

# My list right now 
y_vals = [a, a, a, a, a, a, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, c, c, c, c, c]
```

and I need it to slice every time the number changes. `a`, `b` and `c` are actual numbers, but the numbers are rather long, so I typed it out in `a,b,c`.

I wanted to use the slicing method of `[:x]`, but it's a list of 5000 over numbers, and I'm not sure how to slice a list. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

If you simply want to get sublists with only the same number then don't bother with slicing. A good approach is [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

li = [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2]

for _, group in groupby(li):
    print(list(group))
```

Outputs

```
[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[2, 2]
```

**EDIT**  getting from this to your required list of lists is a straightforward one-liner:

```
output = [list(group) for _, group in groupby(li)]
print(output)
```

Outputs

```
[[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2]]
```

Comment: beautiful solution!

Comment: Both this and pyQueen's answer give me a really beautiful python solution to get all the potential sublist individually, but I guess I wasn't really clear that I needed the final result to be a single list of sublists, hence the tag of grasshopper because the grasshopper environment recognizes a list of sublists as "tree data" which is what I need...>.<

Answer (score 1):

This algorithm isn't really beautiful, but it should work:

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3

y_vals = [a,a,a,a,a,a,b,b,b,b,c,c,c,c,c]

last_break = 0
for i in range(1, len(y_vals)):
    if y_vals[i - 1] != y_vals[i]:
        print(y_vals[last_break: i])
        last_break = i
    if i == len(y_vals) - 1:
        print(y_vals[last_break: i + 1])
```

Result:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[2, 2, 2, 2]
[3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

**Edit:** It will also work for lists like that:

`y_vals = [1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,1,1,1]`

The algorithm by @GotCubes won't.

Answer (score 0):

A solution without slicing:

```
y_vals = [1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,1,1,1]
sub_list = []

for i in range(0, len(y_vals)):
    if ((i < len(y_vals)-1 ) and (y_vals[i] == y_vals[i+1])):
        sub_list.append(y_vals[i])
    else:
        sub_list.append(y_vals[i])
        print(sub_list)
        sub_list=[]
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
[3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
[1, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score -2):

@DeepSpace has the answer you're most likely looking for. However, if you're insistent on slicing, or otherwise getting the indices on which to slice, this might help:

```
# Six 1's, Eleven 2's, Five 3's
y_vals = [1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3]

split_points = [y_vals.count(v) for v in set(y_vals)]
print(split_points)

ind = 0
for i in split_points:
    segment = y_vals[ind:ind+i]
    ind = ind + i
    print(segment)
```

Which gives you:

```
[6, 11, 5]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
[3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

Comment: This only works if there are not repeating values, OP said he wanted to slice everytime the number changes.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I made the (admittedly faulty) assumption that by changing number, it wouldn't go back to previous values. I guess it's dependent on how the data is organized. Thanks for the catch!